# No story missions available in GTA 5

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I have completed the story mission Father/Son but there is no blimp on the map telling me where to go for the next mission. I have switched characters and still no blimp. What do i do? Thanks in advance. :)

PS, the game is for PS3.

Comment: I think I heard that sometimes, the game just lets you screw around a little before giving you the next mission. So I'd say go have fun with side activities and somebody will call you later with the next story mission. But as I said, I'm going from what I've heard. Still waiting on that PC release.

Comment: No problem! If it happens to be the right answer to the question post it below and accept it, it's gonna help the next guy who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @Fredy31 said, sometimes the game requires you to explore a little before your next mission. When we were making Freelancer for PC, we'd require the player to earn a certain amount before the next story mission would unlock, just to ensure they were strong enough to handle it. There may be a similar mechanic at work in GTA but I'm not sure.

GTA is pretty stingy with handing out story missions sometimes, so that blip (which is kind of a blimp, I suppose!) may be rather shy. PS3 here too.

One other thing: the character select wheel (hold down on the d-pad) will show you which characters have available story missions. It appears as a small number near the characters' heads; that number shows how many story missions are available for that character.

[image: Character Wheel from GTA Wiki]

Once you switch to that character, though, starting the mission may be a bit tricky. Sometimes it's a time delay after you meet a new NPC. Also, I recommend you try calling/texting people with your phone. Sometimes you need to connect with another character to start that mission.